# Is a question "how should I do this?" welcome here?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I have a question about how I should design a database for an application, and how to implement this. I have an idea, but it seems cumbersome to implement, so I'm not sure if there is a better way.

Can I ask a question like this on here?

Answer (score 8):

This looks like at least two very broad questions. My advice is to try out some prototype designs/implementations first. This will help you to narrow down your problem, and in turn will make possible to post it as a well defined, concrete and not *too broad* question.

Comment: So is a "here's how I'm trying to do this. Is there a better way?" question a "Too broad" question?

Comment: @iamthesgt From my experience, questions about a "better way" are almost always closed as opinion based. This is also very broad - *better* usually can be defined in many ways. To ask about ways to improve your working code you can try CodeReview.

Answer (score 3):

It looks off-topic for SO, but on-topic for [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), quoting from its 
[*What topics can I ask about here?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help:

> Data Modelling and database-design, including referential-integrity

If you provide some detail of your specific situation, especially the exact part that's got you puzzled and why, I expect it would be OK.

Answer (score -2):

> "seems to be cumbersome"

is subjective, and it is going to invite opinionated commentary, irregardless of whether you question gets flagged or negatived..

Ask your question with the anticipation that people will 'correct' you.. respond to you.. and answer your question...

State your intention, state the implementation you had in mind, and either state what you foresee as an issue, or state the issues you're experiencing in your implementation.

Bare in mind though, you're talking about database design in the context of an application.. 
That's broad, because there is a level of understand and practice that people expect you to introduce yourself to and thus express in your question..

> I'm designing a database for an application. I want the least amount
>   of boilerplate coding and datatype mapping on the application side as
>   possible, but I don't want to use something like the Entity Framework or execute
>   arbitrary commandtext queries.

A general a point of interest, What is the platform and environment that your application runs in.

With all that said, you'll probably find that these types of general questions have been asked already. So you'll probably get the question marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score -4):

It sounds fine to me. I've asked similar questions before, and not had them closed. Just be as specific as you can about what you've done so far (or what your plan is), and what you think the shortcomings of that approach are.

OTOH, I rarely get good answers to questions that are so big and architectural, but ymmv.

Comment: I'm not sure about the quality of answers.. but I certainly get less responses when I'm being descriptive about what I've tried and could determine or deduce..