# Get rid of enterprise architecture

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, clean-up

Looking at [corporate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corporate) it lead me to find questions about  [*enterprise architecture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_architecture)

> ...is a business function concerned with the structures and behaviors of a business, especially business roles and processes that create and use business data.

which is off-topic in SO (these questions might be on topic in [https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7183/31260))

To keep this question focused on a single case, lets talk about
[`[architecture][enterprise]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Barchitecture%5D+%5Benterprise%5D+is%3Aquestion+closed%3A0). This tag combination has <s>33</s>20 open questions most aren't about (include tag excerpt)

- [architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/architecture) "Architecture encompasses the process, artifacts and high-level structure of a solution"
- [enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enterprise) "Enterprise refers to software intended to facilitate the operation of one or more types of business entities, such as cooperatives, companies, universities, and government organizations."

If *enterprise architecture* were on-topic, [enterprise-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enterprise-architecture) <s>should be created and</s><sup>*</sup> those questions should be retagged, but as it isn't, lets review the questions, then

1. if they are on-topic, retag the questions
2. if they are off-topic close the questions and downvote / vote to delete them.

* [enterprise-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enterprise-architecture) was created 6 years ago, it has 19 questions.

Note: There is a similar tag, [enterprise-architect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enterprise-architect) but it refers to a specific tool. Please let the discussion of this tag for another question.

Related

- [How should we tag off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284370/1595451)
- [We are out of new [design]s](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320690/1595451)
- [Where to ask question about software design process / tools?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326350/1595451)
- [Do we really need these Software Engineering related tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355013/1595451)
- [Is this a bad [code-design]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400597/1595451)

Possible Exceptions

- [Very simple Enterprise Application Architecture - making it scale](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3589479/1595451)
- [Proven Java architecture for enterprise applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4413030/1595451)
- [Enterprise java app architecture. Dynamic domain model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10706949/1595451)
- [Architecture for an Enterprise Application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17898472/1595451)
- [What is the best practice for Enterprise level application architecture using MVC5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32641858/1595451)

---

Related tags

- [system-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system-design)

  - Tag excerpt: "Systems design is the process of defining the architecture, components, modules, interfaces, and data for a system to satisfy specified requirements. (wikipedia)"
- [software-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-design)

  - Tag excerpt: "Software design is the activity of deciding what properties, elements, responsibilities, interfaces, relationships and interactions are required in order to create an effective piece of software."
  - Related [Let's improve our [software-design]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397853/1595451). There is a comment suggesting to burninate this tag.
- [application-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-design)

  - Tag excerpt: "Application design (also known as software architecture) is the process of creating a conceptual structured understanding of the different aspects of the application."
- [web-application-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-application-design): No tag excerpt
- [database-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-design)

  - Tag excerpt: "Database design is the process of specifying the structure and thus the logical aspects of a database. The goal of database design is to make a representation of some "universe of discourse" - the types of facts, business rules and other requirements that the database is intended to model."
  - Related [Is a question "how should I do this?" welcome here?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266928/1595451)

Comment: You seem to have entered a rabbit hole of bad tags :p

Comment: You are right. Take me out of here ! :D

Comment: I approve of the title, even when used out of the context of this question.

Comment: This is such a beautiful title. Imagine you're one of the SO developers, and one day you see this.

Comment: The only way to escape the bad tag nightmare is to choose to walk away. Otherwise you'll be trapped eternally as bad tags are continually re-created.

Comment: I kid you not, I ran into a FactoryFactory the other day. It's in Spring Framework.

Comment: As far as I know, a very common use of the term *enterprise architecture* is to describe programming standards in large organizations. People with questions about that are welcome to ask them on Stack Overflow. At any rate, they should be welcome.  Questions about business process design that aren't programming-related would indeed be off-topic.

Comment: @O.Jones I think that using the term *enterprise architecture* to describe *programming standards* might be a wrong use of it unless *programming* is used in a very broad sense. Please provide an example of of a programming standard or a question about one of them that you consider that it's on-topic in [so].

Answer (score 1):

I just removed [`[architecture][enterprise]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Barchitecture%5D+%5Benterprise%5D+is%3Aquestion+closed%3A0) this tag combination from around 20 questions. On some of them I added [system-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system-design) or  other more appropriate tag if that was possible.

Most of this questions nowadays are off-topic as they are primarily opinion based or asking for recommendations. Voted to close accordingly.